# Cucumber calling an external ruby function from a step?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a ruby feature written like this:

```
#./features/sjsonTesting.feature
Feature: Validate DUT JSON
    JSON should be evaluated for all routes in API
    All API routes should return valid JSON
    If JSON is invalid for one or more route in API it has DUT failed 

Scenario Outline: Validate JSON
    Given there is a DUT with <IP> and <USERNAME> and <PASSWORD>
    Then it should return the word PASSED

  Examples:
    |IP             |USERNAME|PASSWORD|
    |'172.168.101.139'|admin   |test    |


I then have step definitions like:
#./features/step_definition/jsonSteps.rb
Given(/^there is a DUT with '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)' and admin and test$/) do |arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4|
  testdev(arg1)#pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then(/^it should return the word PASSED$/) do
  testdev(arg1)#pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end


as well as a support file:
#./support/support.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/http/digest_auth'
require 'json' 
require 'rubygems' 


def is_json(json)
  begin
    JSON.parse(json.to_json)
    return true
  rescue Exception => e
    print e
    return false
  end
end



def gethash(route)
    digest_auth = Net::HTTP::DigestAuth.new
    uri = URI.parse route
    uri.user = 'admin'
    uri.password = 'terraceqam'
    h = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    h.use_ssl = true
    h.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    res = h.request req
    #puts res['www-authenticate']
    auth = digest_auth.auth_header uri, res['www-authenticate'], 'GET'
    #puts auth
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    #puts req
    req.add_field 'Authorization', auth
    res = h.request req
    #puts res.body
    data = JSON.parse(res.body)
    return data
end


def testdev(ip)
   test = "PASSED"
   hash = gethash('https://' + ip +'/views/')
   hash["views"].each do |view|
     routeapi = 'https://' + ip + '/views/' + view
     #print routeapi + "---" 
     subhash =  gethash(routeapi)
     answer = is_json(subhash)  
     if answer == false 
      test = "FAILED"
     end
   end
   return test
end
```

when I run cucumber I get:

```
root@FPGA:/home/robm/code/BDD/testtq# cucumber
Feature: Validate DUT JSON
    JSON should be evaluated for all routes in API
    All API routes should return valid JSON
    If JSON is invalid for one or more route in API it has DUT failed

  Scenario Outline: Validate JSON                                # features/testJson.feature:6
    Given there is a DUT with <IP> and <USERNAME> and <PASSWORD> # features/step_definition/REST_Testing_Steps.rb:2
    Then it should return the word PASSED                        # features/step_definition/REST_Testing_Steps.rb:6

    Examples: 
      | IP                | USERNAME | PASSWORD |
      | '172.168.101.139' | admin    | test     |
      Invalid argument - connect(2) (Errno::EINVAL)
      ./features/support/testJson.rb:30:in `gethash'
      ./features/support/testJson.rb:46:in `testdev'
      ./features/step_definition/REST_Testing_Steps.rb:3:in `/^there is a DUT with '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)' and admin and test$/'
      features/testJson.feature:7:in `Given there is a DUT with <IP> and <USERNAME> and <PASSWORD>'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/testJson.feature:6 # Scenario: Validate JSON

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped)
0m0.058s
```

it has a problem with 
./features/support/testJson.rb:30:in `gethash' which is
    res = h.request req

why cant I get a request ? in that helper code , when i run the code at the command line it works fine.

Comment: You should pass arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 to your `testdev` method, since your arg1 only contains the first portion of the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way would be:

Change to **double** quotes:

```
Examples: 
  | IP                | USERNAME | PASSWORD |
  | "172.168.101.139" | admin    | test     |
```

and match the whole string

```
Given(/^there is a DUT with "(.*?)"$/) do |ip|
  puts  ip  #puts full IP address as string
end
```